# Edit existing shape in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Is it possible to edit an existing shape in draw.io?

I'd like to use "Group" shape (mockup containers > group). However, the blue group heading is too narrow to write any longer word. I need to resize the blue heading and I can't figure out how to do it. I haven't even found an option to edit predefined shape's existing definition (or at least copy and use it as new custom shape).

Comment: This question was bumped by Community User 3 times during 2023.

Answer (score 0):

With the current version 20.7.4 of Draw.io, the blue heading automatically adjusts it's size when you add a long title.

[image]

You can also grab the blue dots around the header to resize the heading block.

[image]